# Why I can not make casting, if model implements IEnumerable<Booking> interface?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am wondering why I can not make casting in my ViewModel`s constructor:

```
public BookingsViewModel()
{
    IEnumerable<Booking> bookingsDB = repository.GetBookings();
    model = bookingsDB; //exception
}
```

It throws me an exception:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Library2.Models.Booking>` to `Library2.Models.Bookings`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

When `GetBookings()` looks like that:

```
public IEnumerable<Booking> GetBookings()
{
    var bookings = context.Bookings.
            Include(i => i.Book).
            Include(i => i.Reader).
            AsEnumerable().
            ToList();
    return bookings;
}
```

And `Bookings` model like that:

```
public class Bookings : IEnumerable<Booking>
{
    private List<Booking> bookingList = new List<Booking>();
    public void AddBooking(Booking booking)
    {
        bookingList.Add(booking);
    }
    public bool DeleteBooking(Booking booking)
    {
        return bookingList.Remove(booking);
    }
    public int BookingList
    {
        get
        {
            return bookingList.Count;
        }
    }
    public Booking this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return bookingList[index];
        }
    }
    public IEnumerator<Booking> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return bookingList.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Where is the problem  if `Bookings` implements `IEnumerable<Booking>`? How to solve the problem?

Comment: `Bookings` is an `IEnumerable<Booking>`. `List<Booking>` is an `IEnumerable<Booking>`. `List<Booking>` is not `Bookings`. Where would a `List<Booking>` get these `AddBooking()`, `DeleteBoocking()` etc from?

Comment: So while every `Bookings` **is** an `IEnumerable<Booking>`, not every `IEnumerable<Booking>` is a `Bookings`.

Answer (score 2):

There's hardly ever any need to implement `IEnumerable<T>` for collections in user code. See also [Why not inherit from List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt). Doing so is probably the wrong approach for the problem you're trying to solve.

Now you have a variable `Bookings model`, where `Bookings : IEnumerable<Booking>`, and you want to assign an `IEnumerable<Booking>` to that variable - you can't. Just as that you can't assign an `Animal` instance to a `Dog` variable - the dog is an animal, but not every animal is a dog.

Either change the type of `model` to `IEnumerable<Booking>`, or change your approach altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can't up-cast like that, `Bookings != IEnumerable<Booking>` even though `Bookings` implements `IEnumerable<Booking>`.

You can think of it like this, my car has a `IDoors` interface, my truck has a `IDoors` interface. However it makes no sense to call them the same, they just share the same doors contract. I can't make my truck into a car no matter how hard I try with a cast implicit or not, all I can do is say they share a similarity in doors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in variable `model`

```
private Bookings model;
```

Although class model implements `IEnumerable<Booking>`, it is not (a parent of) the same class of the object returned by `repository.GetBookings()`.

Compare this with:

```
class Person {...}
class Male : Person {...}
class Female : Person {...}

Person p = new Male();
Female f = p;
```

You can't just assign an object to an object of an unrelated class.

You need to write a converter that converts any sequence of Bookings into an object of class Bookings. The easiest way would be to add a constructor:

```
public Bookings(IEnumerable<Booking> bookings)
{
    this.bookingList = bookings.ToList();
}
```

Note: bookingList is a new list, containing the same elements as bookings. If you add a booking to your original list, it isn't added to your `Bookings` object and vice versa.

Other possible improvements: apparently you plan to store you bookings internally in a 
 list. Why not implement `IList<Booking>`. With very little effort you add a lot of functionality

```
class Bookings : IList<Booking>, IReadonlyList<Booking>, IReadonlyCollection<Booking>
{
    public Bookings()
    {
        this.bookings = new List<Booking>();
    }

    public Bookings(IEnumerable<Booking> bookings)
    {
        this.bookings = bookings.ToList();
    }

    private readonly IList<Booking> bookings;

    public int Count => this.booking.Count;
    public void Add(Booking booking) {this.booking.Add(booking);}
    public void Remove(Booking booking) {this.booking.Remove(booking);}
    public IEnumerator<Booking> GetEnumerator() {return this.booking.GetEnumerator();}
    etc.
}
```

Note: In visual studio, if you right click on the `IList<Bookin>`, and select Quick-actions and refactoring, all functions will be implemented at once. You can even say that all these functions should use `this.booking`.